# Pentaho Data Integration: job keeps running even after Sucess step

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a simple job that collects data from one database and inserts in a table in another database. The job has a start step, transformation and success step.

Ideally the job would start, finish the transformation, mark job as success and then complete.

The issue I am facing is that the when the transformation is completed, it respawns. For testing purposes I am limiting number of rows to 500, the select and insert to db steps happen successfully but then go in a loop.

Attaching screenshots of the job and logs.
[image: job]

Log file (insert_to_wh.ktr is the transformation that keeps repeating):

[image: logs]

Can someone point out why the transformation keeps on restarting and why the job doesn't end after the Success step?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work normally. I created a new job and recreated the same transformation and executed it.
The job that I was executing was copied from another machine and probably that was the reason why the "Success" step wasn't being acknowledged. This [post](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/71038-job-is-running-twice-in-3-2-after-check-if-file-exist/) led me to this conclusion.